# How do clean this code up? Node function taking multiple params with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning mongoose and I have ran into a "clean code" issue. The code works fine and is connected to another file containing my schema. The issue is the function call for "createNewApplicant."

It is getting messy really quick. I am trying to work towards creating an awesome job application / onboarding website for our talent team at my company.

Does anyone have any clean coding tips to shorten the function calls? I've thought of using an object but then I just pass the problem off to my object constructor and it doesn't really solve the issue.

Thank you so much for the time and consideration.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Applicant = require('./Applicant')
const colors = require('colors')

//connecting to mongodb with mongoose
mongoose.connect(MONGOURI,
    () => {
        console.log('connected'.cyan)
    },
    e => console.error(e)
)

//a constructor function which creates a new applicant and stores it in our db
const createNewApplicant = async (fName, lName, eAddress, pNumber, hobbiesArray, addressObject) => {
    try{


        //phone number validation (checks length of phone number)
        if (pNumber.length != 10){
            console.log("incorrect phone number | shutting down function createNewApplicant".bgRed)
            return
        }

        //we have to await because Applicant.create returns a promise
        const applicant = await Applicant.create({
            firstName: fName,
            lastName: lName,
            emailAddress: eAddress,
            phoneNumber: pNumber,
            hobbies: hobbiesArray,
            address: addressObject
         })
        console.log("New Applicant Saved".yellow)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
}

//our function call to create a new applicant
createNewApplicant(
    "Matthew", 
    "Igloo", 
    "myigloo@gmail.com", 
    "9188585576",
    ["running", "skipping", "jumping"],
    { "city": "Tulsa", "state": "OK" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I would suggest you divide everything into smaller chunks

Eg. create multiple folder/files each doing a dedicated tasks..

- `Models` folder contains only the mongoose Models
- `Core` folder contains the actual logic to connect to models (like find, create, update & delete etc) - make it generic i.e. eg. create fn should only accept an object and save it without validating or anything
- `Controller` folder which takes the input, create a format and send it to core for inserting, finding, update or delete
- Also separate your validation and use libraries like joi or yup.. you can perform validation directly in route or in controller; I actually create middleware for this job

If you need more help on how to properly structure, you can chat up with me :)